# Word-2010 hide spelling errors in code paragraphs?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I've been using Microsoft Word for 20 years, and still can't figure this out.

I've selected the paragraph, then Review/Language/Set Proofing Language and unchecked "Do not check spelling or grammar" and still I see these error marks.

[image: Code Snapshot]

Is there any way to hide spelling errors in code blocks as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as I was asking this, I discovered the answer. Left the question and am answering for "future me" and other users' benefit: They're committing the UI error of negatively phrasing the check box action. So the "Do not check spelling or grammar" should be checked!

I am going to add to your answer since I still found it hard to find that option since I would have thought it would have been easily found in Options>Proofing, but it was not obvious. The easiest way is to go to the `Review tab>Language>Set Proofing Language`, then you will see the option you mentioned.

[image]